# Unable to access github, getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error

Tags: windows-7, ssl, github, ssl-certificate

When I access github.com from my office I am getting this error on https://assets-cdn.github.com,

```
SSL connection error
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
```

My PC is brand new and I have Win 7 Professional. The LAN settings is saying detect settings automatically.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Karan, Chrome :)

Answer (score 2):

The certificate of the site is fine so there should be no validation problems. Since you have the problems from office I suggest that there is a SSL intercepting firewall in between, which is common inside companies. In this case you need to import the firewalls interception CA into your system. Check with your local system administrators if this is the case and how to import the necessary certificates.

If this not the case it might be a similar problem but caused by a locally installed security suite, more and more intercept SSL to check encrypted traffic for malware.

In both cases you should see the unexpected issuer when looking into the certificate chain inside the browser (after you temporary accepted an exception).

Comment: Thanks. How to add assets-cdn.github.com domain in exception list of Chrome?

Comment: Why no errors on github.com but on assets-cdn.github.com

Comment: @user960567:   They might have exceptions for sites they don't intercept. Did you already check with the system administrators? Did you have a look at the certificate details in the browser?

Comment: Not yet because contacting admin is a big hedhik  here  :) https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=assets-cdn.github.com&latest